# Why are sort() and reverse() JavaScript methods in-place?

Tags: algorithms, javascript, sorting, immutability

Which are the technical reasons/considerations for the `sort()` and `reverse()` JavaScript array methods to be *in-place* operations instead of returning a new array without modifying the original one, like the `filter()` or `map()` methods do?

I want to understand the technical reasons that drove such decision, why those methods do not follow immutability, and why was decided to modify the array *in-place* instead of returning a new array without modifying the original one... was it for performance reasons? technical constrains? which were the technical drivers of that decision?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for, and how would you _use_ it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't plan to *use* it, I want to understand the technical reasons that drove such decision, I want to understand why those methods do not follow immutability, and why was decided to modify the array *in place* instead of returning a new array without modifying the original one... was it for performance reasons? technical constrains? which are the technical drivers of that decision? I want to understand why was decided in that way and not made them immutable methods.

Comment: Then you'd have to talk to the people who made them. At a certain point it's just because they said so - there are array methods that return new arrays and those that mutate the old one, so there's clearly no fundamental technical constraint.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, I wish I could, but don't know where to go or if I would get an answer from them... but someone familiarized with the implementation and the decision drivers could give me some pointers about this. I don't think only the people who made them know the answer.

Comment: I just sent this Q to Brendan on Twitter. Hopefully he'll answer it :-)

Comment: The surprising design decision isn't so much that they're in-place (most language standard library sorts I'm familiar with are; it's generally more performant and gives the caller flexibility to avoid an allocation if they wish), it's that the in-place methods return the same object as the parameter, which can lead to confusing bugs when chained in a series of otherwise immutable calls. Most language libraries either return void on in-place algorithms or, in the case of Ruby, offer a clearly-labeled "dangerous" version that mutates and returns the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays were originally implemented as hash tables. Keys (buckets) were converted to strings and hashed. [v8](https://github.com/v8/v8) still implements it as a hash table, but also supports a fixed array ([ref](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/js-array.h)).

The [language specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort) (with updates) defines it as in-place, but I couldn't find a relevant design document regarding that decision.

My guess would be that the cost of duplicating the internal structure was relatively expensive at the time. It still can be depending on its size.

However, [here's the official answer](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/1430299734015504393):

> It was based on Java’s static method and also on Perl, both were
> in-place.

Comment: Now we'd have to dig into Java and Perl's design decision :D

Comment: Not really considering the extent of this question. Probably it was retained for familiarity?

Answer (score 12):

Because we can. Because it’s actually cheaper. A method that returns a *different* array either elements sorted or reversed takes twice as much memory.

Filtering cannot return the same array because the number of elements changes, so it returns a new array.

Comment: @MauricioRobayo actually sort does both, mutates it _and returns it_.

Comment: This is surely the correct answer. Let me add my two cents: if someone requires  immutable `sort`, they can implement it easily using the mutable `sort`, just by copying the original array beforehand. However, the other way round it is not possible: if someone requires a more memory efficient in-place version, it would not be possible to use a less efficient immutable `sort` for it. So it is not very surprising that in most standard libs (not only for Javascript) the `sort` function is provided in an in-place fashion (same holds for `reverse`).